# How can i fix the footer at the bottum?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, footer

I tried to fix the footer at the bottom of the page, but it didn't work. so guys, can you please help me?

**note**: you can find footer.css file in a folder called page_parameter_mon_ecole and thanks in advance :)

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

[code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-meninsky-3volf)

Comment: Hello Hassene, could you provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of linking to an external site? Stack Snippets are the best for this. Have you looked into solutions like [this one from Philip Walton](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/)? Bon courage !

Comment: thank you i resolved the problem .